# Flutter Webview Showing Blank Page

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display a linked in page using a Webview widget. However it only shows a blank page. I am running it in debug mode on Simulator - iPhone 11. Note: with other pages like flutter.dev it work ok. Has anyone faced this issue ?

Here is my code:

```
class WebViewLinkdIn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Hexcolor('#1c486d'),
        title: Text('About Marbls'),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/marbls/',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution cannot correct all situations but partly can be accepted.
My code is,

```
WebView(
        debuggingEnabled: true,
        initialUrl: 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/marbls/',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted
)
```

if you on Android, uses-permission about INTERNET in Manifest would be one of the factors.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: one needed to add a row to the Information Property List.
Details: App Transportation Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads: YES.